# New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential throwing Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation, azure-runbook

while executing New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential from Azure Automation runbook its throwing error :

Error occurred while executing SetApplication Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. RequestId: 59574612-93fa-4e13-b409-4fab03e6fe6f DateTimeStamp: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 11:08:33 GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed (Error occurred while executing SetApplication Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. RequestId: 59574612-93fa-4e13-b409-4fab03e6fe6f DateTimeStamp: Mon, 22 Jun 2020 11:08:33 GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed )

I have already provided below API permissions for the Azure application of Automation Account :

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Azure Active Directory Graph API permissions worked for me , Thank you .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVrh1.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Run As Accounts might not have the same permissions against Azure resources as your current Automation account.

**Resolution:-**

Ensure that your Run As account has permissions to access any resources used in your script.

OR

Please go through this Doc:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks